# How to run a piece of code inside _handle_PacketIn function of pox,at time intervals? the maximum recursion depth exceeded error in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, timer, pox

I’m a beginner in python and pox controller. I want to add a code to the pox, to categorize the received packets. I want it to count IP packets travelling between a source & a destination IP/port pair and with identical protocols within a certain period of time.
I want a list like this:

[ [Src ip ,    ds tip,   src port , dst port  ,  protocol=tcp , flow count=x]

[Src ip ,    ds tip,   src port , dst port  ,  protocol=IP , flow count=y]

[ Src ip ,    ds tip,   src port , dst port  ,  protocol=ICMP , flow count=z] ]

I used a list of lists in python , it means 1 list per flow. And I added the flow counting section of the code to the L2_learning component of pox (inside the _handle_PacketIn function). So every time a packet_in is received in the controller, the computation will be executed.

But I got an error: **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**.

I have not used any recursion function in the code!
I have even incremented the stack depth allowed, but the error still exists.

In addition,i don’t know how to schedule the program to fill the list of lists(named: flowlist) at particular time intervals, I’m a bit confused, because every packet that comes to the controller, should be considered in this computation, on the other hand, computing for every packet causes the mentioned error!

**Could you please tell me how to compute the flow count(described above) at particular intervals? And where to place the code for this scheduling in my program?**

**Where to place the command for printing the flowlist, to only print the completed list at that time interval, not printing the list every time a packet is received in controller.**

**And how to solve the  (maximum recursion depth exceeded) error?**

Here is the code:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
class LearningSwitch (object):
flowlist=[]
  def __init__ (self, connection, transparent):
 .......
    LearningSwitch.flowlist=[]
  def _handle_PacketIn (self, event):
   flag=0
   packet = event.parsed
   if packet.type == packet.IP_TYPE:
     ip_packet=packet.payload
             #-------------TCP-----------------
     if (packet.find('tcp')):
       tcp_packet = ip_packet.payload

       for thisflow in LearningSwitch.flowlist:

          if (thisflow[0]==packet.next.srcip and thisflow[1]==packet.next.dstip and thisflow [2]==tcp_packet.srcport and thisflow[3]==tcp_packet.dstport,thisflow[4]== "TCP"):

            thisflow[5]+=1
            flag=1
       if (flag!=1):
              LearningSwitch.flowlist.append([packet.next.srcip,packet.next.dstip,tcp_packet.srcport,tcp_packet.dstport,"TCP",1])

             #---------- ICMP --------------------
     elif (packet.find('icmp')):
      icmp_packet = ip_packet.payload   
      for thisflow in LearningSwitch.flowlist:

        if (thisflow[0]==ip_packet.srcip and thisflow[1]==ip_packet.dstip and  thisflow[4]== "ICMP"):

            thisflow[5]+=1
            flag=1
      if (flag!=1):
         LearningSwitch.flowlist.append([packet.next.srcip,packet.next.dstip,"--","--","ICMP",1])
             #------------ IPV4 ---------------------
     elif (packet.find('ipv4')):

       for thisflow in LearningSwitch.flowlist:

         if (thisflow[0]==packet.next.srcip and thisflow[1]==packet.next.dstip and  thisflow[4]== "IP"):

            thisflow[5]+=1
            flag=1
       if (flag!=1):
         LearningSwitch.flowlist.append([packet.next.srcip,packet.next.dstip,"--","--","IP",1])


   print LearningSwitch.flowlist
          #---- The rest of the code is from L2_learning component

.
.
.
.


class l2_learning (object):

  def __init__ (self, transparent):
    core.openflow.addListeners(self)
    self.transparent = transparent

  def _handle_ConnectionUp (self, event):
     log.debug("Connection %s" % (event.connection,))
     LearningSwitch(event.connection, self.transparent)


def launch (transparent=False, hold_down=_flood_delay):
    """
     Starts an L2 learning switch.
    """
 try:
   global _flood_delay
   _flood_delay = int(str(hold_down), 10)
   assert _flood_delay >= 0
 except:
   raise RuntimeError("Expected hold-down to be a number")

core.registerNew(l2_learning, str_to_bool(transparent))
```

This is the error:

```
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 347, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 214, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 347, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 214, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 347, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 214, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 347, in __cmp__
    return -other.__cmp__(self)
  File "/home/manager/pox/pox/lib/addresses.py", line 214, in __cmp__
   return -other.__cmp__(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Are there any more details in the actual error that can point to where the recursion is happening? Maybe the pox code has a recursive section causing the error.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message ?

Comment: I edited my post and  added the error.you can also  see the-- whole --code i have added to the pox,in my post.
i have not used any recursion function. when i execute for example, a ping command in mininet, the error occurs.

Comment: I even deleted the "print" command, but the error remained. It is probably related to filling the list of lists( flowlist in the code)

Comment: If you run with mininet post the script for the network setup or the command you use to run mininet because I can not reproduce your error. It gives me results as expected `[[IPAddr('10.0.0.1'), IPAddr('10.0.0.2'), '--', '--', 'ICMP', 4], [IPAddr('10.0.0.2'), IPAddr('10.0.0.1'), '--', '--', 'ICMP', 4]]
`

Comment: I didn't use any script. I used the following command in mininet for network setup:                $ sudo mn --topo single,4 --switch ovsk --controller remote.        ( and when i run for example:  mininet> h1 ping h3 , or  when i generate a ddos attack with hping3, the error happens.

Comment: excuse me, i found the cause for the error. there was one small section of the code that i thought is not relevant to this error. i deleted it and the error disappered. thank you

Comment: Now ,could you please tell me  about setting a time interval for computing the flowlist? i don't have any idea how to do that and where to place the code! because i have placed the "print" command inside the _handle_packetin function, all of the updates for flowlist is printed. I want the completed list at particular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a recurring function you need the Timer class from the recoco module.
First import Timer

```
from pox.lib.recoco import Timer
```

Create a function that will print the list. This function belongs in the

> class LearningSwitch (object):

So it is a method of this class and we can refer to it later with self.

```
  def print_list(self):
    """
    just print the list
    Returns:
            nada
    """
    if LearningSwitch.flowlist:
      print LearningSwitch.flowlist
```

Then we create a function that will call every dt seconds the print function above. Passing params the seconds passed between each call

```
  def _timer_func(self, dt):
    """
    recurring function, calls a function every dt seconds
    Returns:
            nada
    """
    Timer(dt, self.print_list, recurring=True)
```

Finally we call the _timer_func in the init of the class

```
self._timer_func(2)
```

Passing here 2 seconds. Delete the print from _handle_PacketIn. You don't need it anymore. 
The complete code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/hFq4KF8G)

The command for mininet used is

```
sudo mn --controller=remote
```

Comment: It's very kind of you to help me.Thank you so much. I really appreciate it